# Merge multiple rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a dataset with 5 rows that I wish to merge into one so that I can use them as unique column identifiers. For example

`Name        Unique No.  Summary  Nominal Voltage  Nominal Voltage  Upstream    Upstream
NaN          NaN         Class    Upstream         Downstream       Constraint  Oppurtunity
(non unique) NaN         NaN      NaN              NaN              Physical    Nan`

I would like the columns to be named

`Name (non unique)   Unique No.   Summary Class   Nominal Voltage Upstream   Nominal Voltage Downstream   Upstream Constraint Phsyical   Upstream Oppurtunity`

So the rows (there are actually 5) would be merged (while ignoring NaNs) which I could then use as unique column names.

Thanks in advance.

As far as I can understand, groupby requires something common between the things being grouped, so can't be used here? The whole database is currently of string type because I thought that would make it easier to join them, but I couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: I may be misreading/misunderstanding the documentation but I didn't think that merge join or concat could do what was required here. They seem to join dataframes, rather than taking the contents of multiple rows and returning them as one row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `apply` with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df.columns = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([x.name] + x.dropna().tolist()))

print (df.columns.tolist())

['Name (non unique)', 
'Unique No.',
'Summary Class', 
'Nominal Voltage Upstream', 
'Nominal Voltage Downstream', 
'Upstream Constraint Physical', 
'Upstream Oppurtunity Nan']
```

If there are some `string` `Nan` - [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) first:

```
df.columns = df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
               .apply(lambda x: ' '.join([x.name] + x.dropna().tolist()))
print (df.columns.tolist())
['Name (non unique)',
 'Unique No.', 
'Summary Class', 
'Nominal Voltage Upstream', 
'Nominal Voltage Downstream', 
'Upstream Constraint Physical',
 'Upstream Oppurtunity']
```

But if need unique column names, the simpliest is:

```
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df.columns.tolist())
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Or assign new unique values of columns:

```
df.columns = list('abcdefg')
print (df.columns.tolist())
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Thank you, so apply is the way! (I appreciate columns a-z etc would be easier but I need the titles for the later code to check and identify, as the columns aren't always in the same order)